# JAX-RS with jboss: diagnosing 400-series HTTP error codes

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs

A recurring issue that I'm having in writing JAX-RS code is that messages related to:

404s ("No root resource matching request path ____ has been found"), and
405s ("No operation matching request path ___ is found")

are supremely unhelpful. It could be the @Consumes or @Produces that isn't proper, the number of parameters, a combination of my path and the chosen method, etc. The log tells me "Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.", but I've set my logging to FINEST and don't see any extra information that would tell me what's going on. What can be done to activate better logging?

I'm somewhat grasping at straws here, but it's a real pain spending up to a half-hour trying to figure out what's wrong with my annotations every time a new endpoint gives nothing but 404s or 405s! I have two endpoints that are virtually identical, but JAX-RS hates one of them and I have no idea why.

Comment: My advice is to keep it simple.  Your packaging or URLs are wrong.  Start by making sure that the root of the context is correct.  Try adding an index.html to see if you can hit the server side and get anything back.

Comment: My server is playing along, I have plenty of endpoints that work fine--it's just unclear what I should be looking at whenever I write a new one for an existing resource and it 404s.

For example, I could write gibberish into the request's type (i.e. POST, PUT, etc.), or the request's content type (i.e. "application/json; charset=UTF-8"), and the server will never complain about it. I would need to go spelunking with a debugger to even see where it's choking.

Comment: Actually, I can't even do breakpoint spelunking, the 404 occurs way before I have any control in the code.

Comment: Sounds like you have context root knocked.  After that you'd have to have a REST URL mapping to each method you want to call.  Where do you specify that?  I use Spring Boot annotated controllers; can't help with JAX-RS.  Spring Boot makes it easy and straightforward.

Comment: How did you set your logging to "FINEST"?

Comment: To turn on FINEST logging, I put this in my log4j properties file (others properties of which which are obeyed, so that configuration is taking effect):

logging.level.org.apache.cxf=FINE

It still advises me to enable FINE/TRACE log though. I'm getting 405 method not allowed currently.